# Popping values from stack

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     stack<int> S;

     int n, x;

     cout << "Enter number of values that     will be pushed into the stack: ";
     cin >> n;

     for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        cout << "Value " << i << ": ";
        cin >> x;
        S.push(x);
     }

     cout << endl;
     cout << "Output: " << endl;

     while(!S.empty()){
          cout << "| ";
          S.pop();
          cout << " |" << endl;
     }
}
```

Hello guys. This my code. If I input these values in the stack: 3, 7, 2, 9, 1 and wanted to display like this:

```
| 1 |
| 9 |
| 2 |
| 7 |
| 3 |
```

But I end up getting:

```
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
|    |
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve] please? The error is quite obvious and you will probably find it yourself if you do that. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `cout << S.top()` before popping.

Comment: Did you expect the `pop` function to print something?

Comment: You `cout` a vertical bar, call a function that has nothing to do with output, and then you `cout` another vertical bar.  What were you expecting, given that sequence of calls?

Answer (score 4):

Use `S.top()` to get the topmost element, `S.pop()` to remove it from top.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     stack<int> S;

     int n, x;

     cout << "Enter number of values that will be pushed into the stack: ";
     cin >> n;

     for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Value " << i << ": ";
        cin >> x;
        S.push(x);
     }

     cout << endl;
     cout << "Output: " << endl;

     while(!S.empty()) {
          /************* Change here ****************/
          cout << "| " << S.top() << " |" << endl;
          S.pop();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two distinct operations [stack::top()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/top) to retrieve the element on the top of the stack and [stack::pop()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) to remove the element on the top, which allows to retrieve the next element via `stack::top()` and so on.
So call first `top()` then `pop()`.